# Force call to ViewPager instantiateItem

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a view that contains a ViewPager, whose visibility is set to `GONE` on startup. By introducing a print on the pager `instantiateItem` method I noticed that this method is only called when the pager is set to `VISIBLE`.

Since the instantiation seems to be a bit heavy, the user is able to notice a slight "bump" when the pager must be shown for the first time (which is when the instantiation method is called).

However, at app startup, there is loading screen (establishing connections, etc), and I would like to be able to make the pager call `instantiateItem` while that loading screen is running (but without showing the view to the user).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is in place as an optimization because there would be no reason to instantiate items if the user may not ever see them.

If `instantiateItem` is such a long process, then you can call this on your adapter yourself and cache the instantiated items.  This is ok if you don't have that many items.

Otherwise, you have to make ViewPager think it's visible.  Rather than setting it's visibility, you can just hide it behind a View then make the View go away when everything is ready. Just make sure you capture touch events on the View so they don't get passed down to the ViewPager.